# How to force WebSphere AS 8 to use a specific JSF implementation?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, websphere, myfaces

I have an old enterprise application that was developed using WAS 6.1, now my company is trying to perform the implementation of that application in WAS 8. But I am having troubles rendering the JSF content, there are some links that when clicked the JS debugger says 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: myfaces is not defined`  being the rendered HTML:

```
onclick="return myfaces.oam.submitForm('top_nav:frmTopNav','top_nav:frmTopNav:lnkCP',null,[['default_sort','name']]);"
```

So I think it's not rendering it well because of the different versions of JSF between my old application and WAS 8.

Now I decided to force it, downloading the MyFaces 1.1 with Tomahawk 1.1.7 and putting them in the WEB-INF/lib folder, and now it says `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Class org.mything.LocaleViewHandler is no javax.faces.application.ViewHandler`

Why could this be happening?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from WAS 8 infocenter, [Configuring JavaServer Faces implementation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tweb_jsf.html&resultof=%22third%22%20%22party%22%20%22parti%22%20%22JSF%22%20%22jsf%22%20)

> If you want to use a third-party JSF implementation that is not
> shipped with the product, then:
>
> - Keep the configuration set to MyFaces.
> - Add the third-party listener to the web.xml file that is required.
> - Add the third-party implementation Java archive (JAR) files to the
>   application as an isolated shared library and associate it with your application.

On the above referenced page you may find details on [Creating shared libraries](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tcws_sharedlib_create.html) and [Associating shared libraries with applications or modules](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tcws_sharedlib_app.html).

Comment: You are quoting the first point wrong: "If you are using a third-party MyFaces implementation, set the JSF implementation to Sun RI". However it does not matter, because none works!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using [PARENT_LAST](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzatz%2F51%2Fprogram%2Fclsadmcns.htm) classloading.

Otherwise it will load its own JSF 2.0 libs first and your class doesn't match the interface. You should check though if you could update to MyFaces 2.0.