# Is it a MyFaces or Mojarra application?

Tags: jsf, myfaces, mojarra

An application is installed to WebSphere 8. I would like to know if there is any way to check if the application is using MyFaces or Mojarra and the version used.

Answer (score 2):

Different ways for checking **which vendor** is it:

- [`FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVendor();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getImplementationVendor%28%29) returns vendor's name.
- You could otherwise look into your classpath to find jsf jars, myfaces ones usually start with `myfaces-` prefix.
- Sometimes some specific `myfaces-` params [can be found](https://myfaces.apache.org/wiki/core/user-guide/getting-started/configuring-myfaces.html) in the web context (web.xml). You could search for them.

For the **version**, you can also retrieve its number from the `FacesContext`:

[`FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getImplementationVersion%28%29)

That will return the major implementation version. To check the minor ones, see the second link attached, once you know the vendor.

---

[It seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477995/how-to-force-websphere-as-8-to-use-a-specific-jsf-implementation) WebSphere 8 uses a MyFaces implementation by default. You could find the JSF implementation jar and open its *MANIFEST.MF* file, the implementation version [must be stored there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141728/how-to-check-replace-the-myfaces-version-used-by-websphere-8-5).

**See also:**

- [How to detect current JSF-Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125782/how-to-detect-current-jsf-version)
- [Access JSF and Primefaces version numbers programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355985/access-jsf-and-primefaces-version-numbers-programatically/18356208#18356208)