# Omnifaces Filter and Async Servlet

Tags: servlets, java-ee-6, websphere-8, servlet-3.0, omnifaces

I'm using WebsphereApplicationServer 8.5.5.9

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rovr_specs.html

Java version is 1.7 
But JSF is 2.0
CDI 1.0 (but this is an open question)

So I have to use OminiFaces 1.8.3 ?

Change are not possible:

- [How to force WebSphere AS 8 to use a specific JSF implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477995/how-to-force-websphere-as-8-to-use-a-specific-jsf-implementation)
- [How to check (replace) the MyFaces version used by Websphere 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141728/how-to-check-replace-the-myfaces-version-used-by-websphere-8-5)
- [A IBM example](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=6eaab321-76d4-42ab-8ae6-e366994448f4#repliesPg=1)

I use Omnifaces in a lot of case but...

I have to write some Async Servlet

- simple example: [here](http://jlaskowski.blogspot.it/2012/05/watki-podczas-obsugi-asynchronicznego.html)
- more complex example [here](http://jlaskowski.blogspot.it/2012/05/watki-podczas-obsugi-asynchronicznego.html)

but i had

> SRVE8010E: The current request does not support asynchronous servlet
>   processing.
>       Explanation   One of the servlets or filters in the request does not support asynchronous servlets.
>       Action    Do not use asynchronous servlets or enable asynchronous processing for all the servlets and filters in the chain by adding the
>   async-supported element to the component definitions.

Looking at the various filter; I had mine and the CacheControlFilter but removin one by one them I obtain the above error only with CacheControlFilter so I think that this filter can't be used.

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>noCache</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>cache10seconds</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>expires</param-name>
            <param-value>10s</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>cache6hours</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>expires</param-name>
            <param-value>6h</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>cache1days</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>expires</param-name>
            <param-value>1d</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>noCache</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cache6hours</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cache1days</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Ok so the question is.. Can I filter an AsyncServlet with a WebFilter? I think it is possible.   Or is the WebFilter  not compatible with Async Servlet  I have discovered this in using filter in Omnifaces and I haven't read nothing about That so If is possible to filter an AsyncServlet it could be useful add an async webfilter .

Comment: Thanks 

Ok but the filter for async context shouldn't be built async  
https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/asynchronous-support-in-servlet-30